Debuging Failed Flutter/Dart application
Good day all,
I'm pretty new to Android development. I'm trying to launch a Flutter app in debugging mode, but I'm getting lots of errors.
Background: I had a developer working on the app for me while I was working on the backend but he bailed out and left me out dry. I do front-end and backend dev but not mobile app dev. One thing that I insisted that the code was pushed to my repo after each major update. now I have the code and am trying to run it to see which stage of the development it is in. After installing the development environment (Android Studio, Dart, Flutter, ...) I'm unable to get it to launch in debugging mode. see errors
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
CMake Deprecation Warning at K:/FAS-Flutter/build/windows/x64/extracted/firebase_cpp_sdk_windows/CMakeLists.txt:17 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.

/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-2.2.1/lib/style.dart(239,47): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'headline1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-2.2.1/lib/style.dart(240,47): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'headline2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-2.2.1/lib/style.dart(241,47): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'headline3' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-2.2.1/lib/style.dart(242,47): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'headline4' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-2.2.1/lib/style.dart(243,47): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'headline5' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-2.2.1/lib/style.dart(244,47): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'headline6' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-2.2.1/lib/style.dart(245,49): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart(236,20): error G75B77105: Member not found: 'MediaQuery.boldTextOverride'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/handle_overlay.dart(60,40): error G75B77105: Member not found: 'fadeDuration'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart(186,20): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart(190,24): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'void Function(TapUpDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpDetails)?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart(195,26): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart(196,31): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragStartDetails)?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart(197,32): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails, DragUpdateDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpdateDetails)?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart(198,29): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'void Function(DragEndDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragEndDetails)?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/math.dart(180,22): error G75B77105: Member not found: 'MediaQuery.boldTextOverride'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_html-2.2.1/lib/html_parser.dart(173,62): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart(82,55): error G44692867: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart(83,58): error GE5CFE876: The method 'markNeedsPlacement' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart(84,54): error GE5CFE876: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart(132,55): error G44692867: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart(133,58): error GE5CFE876: The method 'markNeedsPlacement' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart(134,54): error GE5CFE876: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/layout_grid.dart(212,20): error G55BD5BF6: Inferred type argument 'AutoPlacement' doesn't conform to the bound 'Enum?' of the type variable 'T' on 'EnumProperty'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-3.1.4/lib/src/guid.dart(31,9): error G5FE39F1E: Type 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' not found. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-3.1.4/lib/src/guid.dart(31,9): error G027421CC: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' isn't a type. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-3.1.4/lib/src/guid.dart(51,17): error G311314CC: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-3.1.4/lib/src/guid.dart(55,31): error G311314CC: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/crasi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-3.1.4/lib/src/guid.dart(99,17): error G311314CC: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\1b1223a11a6a97c487e400c5998f0b29\flutter_windows.dll.rule;K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\6efcf5ccc410d172ff7e9ee448e987a6\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [K:\FAS-Flutter\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Error: Build process failed.

Exited (1).

Any help would be appreciated to get me started on this thing.

It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as text, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Lastly, take a look at No Images Please
